# DAX PowerBI: Need a Total of a column for a full year whilst filtering the rest of the table by Year to Date

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that is working correctly shows values based on the months selected, I now need to add a column that add together everything for the full year, including future months without affecting the rest of the table.

I have used `Calculate(Budget[BudgetValue], All (Period[PeriodFK]))` also I have tried `Calculate(Budget[BudgetValue], AllExcept (Person[SalesPersonId]))` and `Calculate(Budget[BudgetValue], AllExcept (Period[PeriodFK]))`

But both are still filtering the value I need to keep as a full year total. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried marking your calendar / period table as a [Date Table](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/time-intelligence-in-power-bi-desktop/)?

Comment: Yes, its more the page level filters on the PowerBI report that are filtering it when I need it to ignore one column. I can get the value in the Tabular Model.

Comment: Looks like the measure coming into the next measure was getting filtered. Got around this and resolved the issue with CALCULATE((SUM(Budget[Value1]) + SUM(Budget[Value2]),FILTER(ALL(Period),Period[Year]=MAX(Period[Year])))

Comment: you need a sum in your measure